# Bootstrap Modal in Rails - closing and reopening and passing params

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I show a bootstrap modal with some checkboxes:

```
    <span class="pull-right">
      <%= check_box_tag 'role_ids[]', "all", false, class: 'sel' -%><span class="right-label"><%= t('.suspend.suspend_all_roles') %></span><br>
      <% UserRole.all.each do |role| %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'role_ids[]', role.id, false,class: 'sel' -%><span class="right-label"><%= role.user_role %></span><br>
       <% end %>
    </span>
```

There is also an OK button and a Cancel button.

When the user opens the modal and they can select some checkboxes.  But I am getting an issue where the params are nil when:

1. Open the modal
2. check some checkboxes
3. Cancel the modal
4. Reopen the modal (the same checkboxes will be checked as they are 'remembered')
5. Click OK

When the Controller action is called - the `params[:role_ids]` are `nil`.

Any idea why this would happen?  It is not passing which checkboxes have been checked

Is there a way to have the checkboxes all unchecked when the modal is closed and reopened?

edit:

I tried using this JS to uncheck all the checkboxes when the modal is closed and reopened but the `params[:role_ids]` are still coming through as nil:

```
   $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
        $others.prop('checked', false);
        $suspend_all.prop('checked', false)
        });
```

It works the first time you open the modal, but not when it is canceled and reopened.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix this was by using AJAX instead to open the modal.  So the modal is retrieved from the server each time it is opened.  It was a lot more hassle to setup but it works fine.